# Bootstrap navbar and leaflet zoom controls

Tags: leaflet, zoom, mapcontrol, bootstrap-framework

I'm using the THE MAP GUY(DE) Bootstrap template and applying it to `leaflet` using the code below.  The issue I'm having is that the zoom-control doesn't toggle right on page load.  It will only after you collapse and then re-expand the panel again.  How can I get the zoom to toggle on load?  What am I missing?

You can see the OL3 here:  http://jumpinjackie.github.io/bootstrap-viewer-template/2-column/index.html.

JavaScript:

```
function applyMargins() {
    var leftToggler = $(".mini-submenu-left");
    if (leftToggler.is(":visible")) {
        $("#map .leaflet-control-zoom")
                .css("margin-left", 5)
                .css("margin-Top", 50)
                .removeClass("zoom-top-opened-sidebar")
                .addClass("zoom-top-collapsed");
    } else {
        $("#map .leaflet-control-zoom")
                .css("margin-left", 2 + $(".sidebar-left").width())
                .css("margin-Top", 5)
                .removeClass("zoom-top-opened-sidebar")
                .removeClass("zoom-top-collapsed");
    }
}

function isConstrained() {
    return $(".sidebar").width() == $(window).width();
}

function applyInitialUIState() {
    if (isConstrained()) {
        $(".sidebar-left .sidebar-body").fadeOut('slide');
        $('.mini-submenu-left').fadeIn();
    }
}

$(function () {
    $('.sidebar-left .slide-submenu').on('click', function () {
        var thisEl = $(this);
        thisEl.closest('.sidebar-body').fadeOut('slide', function () {
            $('.mini-submenu-left').fadeIn();
            applyMargins();
        });
    });

    $('.mini-submenu-left').on('click', function () {
        var thisEl = $(this);
        $('.sidebar-left .sidebar-body').toggle('slide');
        thisEl.hide();
        applyMargins();
    });

    var map = L.map('map').setView([40.91, -96.63], 4);

    L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
    }).addTo(map);

    L.control.mousePosition().addTo(map);

    L.control.scale().addTo(map);

    new L.Control.GeoSearch({
        provider: new L.GeoSearch.Provider.OpenStreetMap()
    }).addTo(map);

    var locationFilter = new L.LocationFilter().addTo(map);

    $(window).on("resize", applyMargins);
    applyInitialUIState();
    applyMargins();
});

//Bootstrap modal dragging
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".modal-draggable .modal-dialog").draggable({
        handle: ".modal-header", cursor: "move"
    });
});
```

CSS

```
body { overflow: hidden; }

.navbar-offset { margin-top: 50px; }
#map { position: absolute; top: 50px; bottom: 0px; left: 0px; right: 0px; }
#map .leaflet-control-zoom { font-size: 1.2em; }

.zoom-top-opened-sidebar {
    margin-top: 5px; 
    left: 2px;
}
.zoom-top-collapsed {margin-top: 45px; }

.mini-submenu{
    display:none;  
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.46);
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding: 9px;  
    /*position: relative;*/
    width: 42px;
    text-align: center;
  }

.mini-submenu-left {
    position: absolute;
    top: 1px;
    left: 1.2em;
    z-index: 40;
}

#map { z-index: 35; }

.sidebar { z-index: 45; }

.main-row { position: relative; top: 5px; left: 2px; }

.mini-submenu:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
}

.slide-submenu{
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45);
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 8px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

HTML

```
 <body>
    <div class="container">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-default" role="navigation">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Map Viewer (2-column layout)</a>
          </div>
          <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
              <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                  <li class="divider"></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                  <li class="divider"></li>
                  <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
              </div>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
            </form>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
              <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
              <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                  <li class="divider"></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
            </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
            </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
          </nav>
        </div>
      </nav>
      <div class="navbar-offset"></div>
      <div id="map">
      </div>
      <div class="row main-row">
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3 sidebar sidebar-left pull-left">
          <div class="panel-group sidebar-body" id="accordion-left">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                  <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#layers">
                    <i class="fa fa-list-alt"></i>
                    Layers
                  </a>
                  <span class="pull-right slide-submenu">
                    <i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i>
                  </span>
                </h4>
              </div>
              <div id="layers" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                <div class="panel-body list-group">
                  <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
                    <i class="fa fa-globe"></i> Open Street Map
                  </a>
                  <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
                    <i class="fa fa-globe"></i> Bing
                  </a>
                  <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
                    <i class="fa fa-globe"></i> WMS
                  </a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                  <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#properties">
                    <i class="fa fa-list-alt"></i>
                    Properties
                  </a>
                </h4>
              </div>
              <div id="properties" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                <div class="panel-body">
                  <p>
                  Yada Yad Yad
                  </p>
                  <p>
                  Yada Yad Yad
                  </p>
                  <p>
                  Yada Yad Yad
                  </p>
                  <p>
                  Yada Yad Yad
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="mini-submenu mini-submenu-left pull-left">
        <i class="fa fa-list-alt"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Comment: I'm looking for an answer to this as well? Did you ever solve the issue?

Comment: No... Sorry, not yet.

Comment: I am not sure I understand. when I click on the link you gave, the zoom-control appears right away on page load ( without the collapse-expand trick). Have you solved the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
 L.control.zoom({
      position:'topright'
     }).addTo(map);
```

Sry, for the lack of explanation I ll try to be more comprehensive next time. So, if I understood the question correctly, problem lies in position of zoom in & out control.

On Leaflet doc I've found this [http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#control-options][1]

First, I disabled zoom control when rendering a map (which is topleft by default) Like this:

```
//disable zoomControl
var map = L.map('map',{zoomControl: false}).setView([40.91, -96.63], 4);
```

And then I added this block of code

```
L.control.zoom({
          position:'topright'// default is topleft
         }).addTo(map);
```

Here is full block of code that I copied from site above

I just copied script tag

```
     function applyMargins() {
    var leftToggler = $(".mini-submenu-left");
    if (leftToggler.is(":visible")) {
        $("#map .leaflet-control-zoom")
                .css("margin-left", 5)
                .css("margin-Top", 50)
                .removeClass("zoom-top-opened-sidebar")
                .addClass("zoom-top-collapsed");
    } else {
        $("#map .leaflet-control-zoom")
                .css("margin-left", 2 + $(".sidebar-left").width())
                .css("margin-Top", 5)
                .removeClass("zoom-top-opened-sidebar")
                .removeClass("zoom-top-collapsed");
    }
}

function isConstrained() {
    return $(".sidebar").width() == $(window).width();
}

function applyInitialUIState() {
    if (isConstrained()) {
        $(".sidebar-left .sidebar-body").fadeOut('slide');
        $('.mini-submenu-left').fadeIn();
    }
}

$(function () {
    $('.sidebar-left .slide-submenu').on('click', function () {
        var thisEl = $(this);
        thisEl.closest('.sidebar-body').fadeOut('slide', function () {
            $('.mini-submenu-left').fadeIn();
            applyMargins();
        });
    });

    $('.mini-submenu-left').on('click', function () {
        var thisEl = $(this);
        $('.sidebar-left .sidebar-body').toggle('slide');
        thisEl.hide();
        applyMargins();
    });
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //DISABLING ZOOM CONTROL WHEN LOADING A MAP/////
    var map = L.map('map',{zoomControl: false}).setView([40.91, -96.63], 4);

    ///ZOOM CONTROL POSITION///
    /////////////////////////////
      L.control.zoom({
      position:'bottomright'
     }).addTo(map);

    L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
    }).addTo(map);




    L.control.scale({}).addTo(map);


    var locationFilter = new L.LocationFilter().addTo(map);

    $(window).on("resize", applyMargins);
    applyInitialUIState();
    applyMargins();
});

//Bootstrap modal dragging
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".modal-draggable .modal-dialog").draggable({
        handle: ".modal-header", cursor: "move"
    });
});
```

Comment: Please edit for clarity and provide context on why this may work/where in the code to insert this.  Please see the community help page to see what makes a good answer: http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with a fixed Bootstrap navbar, for me this line solved everything:

```
#map { top: 50px; }
```

See all CSS of my map:

```
#map {
    top: 50px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    position:relative;
}
```